# Is there a guideline on writing message that are shown to users of an app?

Tags: coding-standards, user-experience, error-messages

Is there any guideline on writing message which are shown to the user of an app using toast?

For example, if an error occurred, should the app display

> Failed writing to the file

or

> Failed writing to the file.

Should sentences use full stop? I don't see full stops used in some language REPLs when there is only one sentence. Is there any standard way?

Comment: I think you should ask this question in https://ux.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Microsoft has some good guidelines on presentation, style and tone of UI text: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/uxguide/text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recognize a general industry-wide problem. As long as I have been in interactive software development I have encountered cringing language. I can always tell it is bad, I can always make it better (and I usually do), but I have no cookbook to do this. It would be great to have a standard rule set that everyone (especially those who do not see the problem) can apply. This is an issue for UI messages and logging alike.

What I have seen:

- Incomplete sentences, lazy staccato style.
- Use of exclamation marks for no reason.
- Use of all capitals for no reason.
- Useless information on a level meaningless to the user.
- Active/personal form instead of passive form ("Cannot write to file" instead of "The file could not be written.").
- Frills like lots of dots at the end or dashes over and
  under.

To a user it often feels rude or indifferent. I have seen UI guidelines but little on language.

I recognize this has been more an elaboration of the question than an answer so far. Here's what I usually try to apply.

- Use full yet brief sentences.
- Be polite.
- Be considerate of the message level (info, warning, error).
- Use passive form (the system is not a person).
- Provide only meaningful information. If you want to show an exception message, introduce it, like "An exception occurred:".
- Do not present puzzles, make it clear what is expected if the user needs to do something (different).

Answer (score 1):

Captions, titles, menu items and such should not end in a full-stop.

So if `Failed writing to the file` is a dialog title, that is okay.

For content, a message a full stop is often missing, if the text contains just one sentence. This is not correct. In one case even I fail (colon style):

```
Failed writing to the file: C:\Temp\interesting_news.pdf
```

I use this style a bit too often, as real comma like quotes are cumbersome.

My rule: more than one sentence, or a long sentence should end with a period.

The same flexibility holds for (bullet) lists

```
         Xyz:      Xyz:      Xyz.
∙ aaa    ∙ aaa;    ∙ aaa,    ∙ Aaa.
∙ bbb    ∙ bbb;    ∙ bbb,    ∙ Bbb.
∙ ccc    ∙ ccc.    ∙ ccc.    ∙ Ccc.
```

Without period for  captions, like on slides.